# issue in inserting data into mysql database table : showing DB error

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

I have a DB table called `history` having the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `history_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sql_query` text,
  `authuser` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=618 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am trying to run a script in php which is returning the following error:

```
HIST DB Error :(INSERT into history(history_date,sql_query,ip,authuser,authId) VALUES(1441378485,'UPDATE itemstypes SET typedesc="Keyboard",hassoftware=0 WHERE id="10"','10.16.7.44','superadmin','6')):Incorrect datetime value:1441378485 for column 'history_date' at row 1
```

If I run the query `INSERT into history(history_date,sql_query,ip,authuser,authId) VALUES(1441378485,'UPDATE itemstypes SET typedesc="Keyboard",hassoftware=0 WHERE id="10"','10.16.7.44','superadmin','6')` through my localhost's phpmyadmin it is inserted but as the datatype is not matching, in history_date column, `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is storing. 
Now when I run the same in live server, I am getting the above error. 
What might be the issue? Please let me know. Is there any configuration issue in server? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `1441378485` is not a valid datetime the format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 0):

change your date format, like

```
INSERT into history(history_date,sql_query,ip,authuser,authId)
VALUES(2015-09-16 00:00:00,'UPDATE itemstypes
SET typedesc="Keyboard",hassoftware=0 WHERE id="10"','10.16.7.44','superadmin','6')
```

Comment: I know that if I change the date then it will work but why my script is halted after running this query. Normally it should insert the record with improper date. Could you please let me know any ini file related changes I need to do?